# How can I format the date like this in search-result.tpl?

Tags: search

In node.tpl I have

```
<div class="imported-text">

Created on <?php print date('l', $node->created); ?>, the <?php print date('jS', $node->created); ?> of <?php print date('F Y', $node->created); ?>.

</div>
```

But when I place this in search-result.tpl I get an error. `<?php print $info_split['date'] ?>` can only use the short format AFAIK.

Answer (score 3):

I find it is generally best to do things in a consistent way and since the drupal [template_preprocess_search_result()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7) function uses Drupal's format_date() function I recommend also using that when overriding things.

So to leave the date in the default info variable but change the format I would do this, in my template.php file of my theme (or a custom module, depending on my requirements):

```
/**
 * Variable preprocessor for the search result template.
 *
 * @see search-result.tpl.php
 */
function MODULE_OR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $result = $variables['result'];

  // Override the date format.
  if (!empty($result['date'])) {
    $variables['info_split']['date'] = format_date($result['date'], 'custom', 'l, \t\h\e jS \o\f F Y');
  }
  // Reset the info variable based on the new date.
  $variables['info'] = implode(' - ', $variables['info_split']);
}
```

If I wanted a date variable available in my template that was separate from the info variable I would do this:

```
/**
 * Variable preprocessor for the search result template.
 *
 * @see search-result.tpl.php
 */
function MODULE_OR_THEME_NAME_preprocess_search_result(&$variables) {
  $result = $variables['result'];

  // Add a custom date variable for use in the template.
  $variables['custom_date'] = '';
  if (!empty($result['date'])) {
    $variables['custom_date'] = format_date($result['date'], 'custom', 'l, \t\h\e jS \o\f F Y');
  }
}
```

Then to use that variable in the template file you would do something like this:

```
<?php if ($custom_date): ?>
  <div class="date">
    <php print $custom_date; ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Something I recommend to make things even a bit better again is instead of using the 'custom' date formatter, make a preset for "l, \t\h\e jS \o\f F Y" in the Drupal UI at admin/config/regional/date-time, then use that preset like this:

```
format_date($result['date'], 'preset_name');
```

Then you can easily change the format in future via the UI.

In this case I would recommend calling the preset "Search result date" or something along those lines so that you know what it is used for when looking the the UI and you know what will be affected if you change it.

Comment: I appreciate the help very much but neither of these worked for me. #1 gave me the error undefined variable info. The second one displayed nothing, no error though. If it matters I'm using a bootstrap subtheme. I cleared all caches both times.

Comment: Went back and tried this again and it worked. Setting l, \t\h\e jS \o\f F Y as short did, that is. Thanks again.

Comment: Whoops sorry, I was using an undefined variable $result. I fixed the examples above to define it as $result = $variables['result'].

Comment: No worries. Should I keep it as short or use the php? Also I just noticed that it doesn't match the node creation date for some reason. I'm using feeds to set the node date as the rss items date. $node->created works though

Comment: I probably wouldn't use short because it isn't very short. I would use medium or long if I was to use a default format. I would only do that though if I was using that format elsewhere on the site. If I was only using that format for search results and nothing else I would make a custom date format via the UI and use that.

Comment: $node->created is always the node created date so if it is wrong then the date is being set incorrectly somewhere else when the node is saved. Sounds like it might be related to your feeds functionality.

Comment: The first example is giving me "Notice: Undefined variable: info in podliberty_preprocess_search_result() (line 57"

Comment: Stack exchange having enter not be a line break is really annoying. Wow. Anyway line 57 is $variables['info'] = implode(' - ', $info);

Comment: Wow I really rushed that one. I fixed that example above now.